# get difference between 3 lists

Tags: python, list, set

I am working on differences of lists.

```
>>a = [1, 2, 3]
>>b = [2, 4, 5]
>>c = [3, 2, 6]
```

Symmetric difference between 2 sets can be done using:

```
>>z = set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))
>>print z
>>set([1, 3, 4, 5])
```

How to get difference between 3 sets?
For difference of 3 sets, expected output is :

```
expected output : set([1, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Yes, what's the expected output?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, how would that give the result? That would have  contain `2`.

Comment: It should give differences between 3 lists. i.e. [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: It will skip similar elements from all 3 lists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : no it gives wrong result. It need only those elements which are uncommon. 2 should not be present.

Comment: what do you want is [1, 4, 5, 6]??

Comment: @MassimoCosta : please see I have updated my question with expected output

Comment: why 3?? is in 2 of three list

Comment: need to skip only those elements which are not common among 3 lists

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just subtract the intersection from the union:

```
In [1]: a = set([1, 2, 3])

In [2]: b = set([2, 4, 5])

In [3]: c = set([3, 2, 6])

In [4]: (a | b | c) - (a & b & c)
Out[4]: set([1, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Or, to generalise to an arbitrary collection of sets:

```
In [10]: l = [a, b, c]

In [11]: reduce(set.union, l) - reduce(set.intersection, l)
Out[11]: set([1, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

or:

```
In [13]: set.union(*l) - set.intersection(*l)
Out[13]: set([1, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

(The latter is probably preferable.)

Comment: can we find similar elements of 3 using such method?

Comment: @sam: Not sure I understand the question. Do you mean `a & b & c`?

Comment: I mean If I want to find similar element of 3 sets. i.e. 2

Comment: @sam: Well, as I said, `a & b & c`.

Comment: I think the later should be: `set().union(a, b, c) - set(a).intersection(b, c)`

Comment: As long as `l` doesn't need to be re-used, you can end up with: `set().union(*l) - set(l.pop()).intersection(*l)` or if it does `i = iter(l); set().union(*l) - set(next(i)).intersection(*i)`

Comment: And probably make the `iter` one `next(i, ())` to handle empty `l`'s

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
def difflists(*lists):
    sets = map(set, lists)
    return set.union(*sets) - set.intersection(*sets)

print difflists(a, b, c)    # set([1, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

If you want to exclude elements that are present more than once instead:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

def difflists(*lists):
    items = Counter(it for lst in lists for it in lst)
    return [it for it, count in items.iteritems() if count == 1]

print difflists(a, b, c)    # [1, 4, 5, 6]
```

This methods accept any number of lists

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2, 4, 5]
>>> c = [3, 2, 6]
>>> z1 = set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))
>>> z2 = set(b).symmetric_difference(set(c))
>>> print z1.union(z2)
set([1, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

@NPE that answer doesn't work as expected since it relies on the result of the proceeding operations. In your example you can see the '3' overlapping from the first to the third but still being included in the result.

```
>>> a = set(('a','b','c')) 
>>> b = set(('c','d','e'))
>>> c = set(('e','f','g'))
>>> (a | b | c) - (a & b & c)
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f'])
```

This happens because it does the intersection of 'a' to 'b' and then the intersection to 'c'. To fix this you could:

```
>>> (a | b | c) - ((a & b) | (a & c) | (b & c))
set(['a', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'f'])
```

Also to save two operations you could get the the symmetric difference of two, union with the third, then do the difference of the union of the intersections of the first and third and second and third.

```
>>> ((a ^ b) | c) - ((a & c) | (b & c))
set(['a', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'f'])
```